# How to extract a dynamic last value from a Debug Sampler and pass it in the next request?

Tags: jmeter

So the scenario is, I need to call an endpoint which will return the below response and from the response I want to extract all the values of `createdAt` field (which can be found in Debug Sampler) and take the last value from the `createdAt` field and pass it in th enext request.

I did lot of googling, but I couldn't find a single trick that fits this situation. Can someone please guide me as I am new to `JMeter`?

```
Response:
{"data":[{"id":5741,"createdAt":1584434217000,"updatedAt":null,"contentType":"CHECKOUT","author":null,"actionType":"CAMPAIGN","actionId":353,"comment":"Jhgjhj","deadlineAt":1585039017000,"campaignType":"FEE","recurring":"WEEKLY","amount":3.0000,"currency":"EUR","fulfilled":false},{"id":5710,"createdAt":1584375135000,"updatedAt":null,"contentType":"VOTE","author":{"id":304,"teamName":"Team Content","teamShirtNumber":null,"role":"PLAYER","firstName":"Stefanie","lastName":"Player08","profilePictureReference":"5b5bd132-c285-49e2-98b2-857259391c86"},"labels":[{"id":256,"label":"Yes \uD83D\uDC7B"},{"id":257,"label":"No"}],"text":"Vote content card not visible in the stream 02","backgroundImage":"983cc194-497e-4e6e-9ab3-ca2147469252","result":{"answers":[],"myAnswer":null},"votingEndAt":1587404222000},{"id":5709,"createdAt":1584373151000,"updatedAt":null,"contentType":"CHECKOUT","author":null,"actionType":"CAMPAIGN","actionId":349,"comment":"test06","deadlineAt":1584977951000,"campaignType":"DONATION","recurring":null,"amount":2.0000,"currency":"EUR","fulfilled":false},{"id":5704,"createdAt":1584372961000,"updatedAt":null,"contentType":"CHECKOUT","author":null,"actionType":"CAMPAIGN","actionId":348,"comment":"test05","deadlineAt":1584977761000,"campaignType":"SPECIAL_PAYMENT_AND_SUBVENTION","recurring":null,"amount":2.0000,"currency":"EUR","fulfilled":false},{"id":5675,"createdAt":1584365852000,"updatedAt":null,"contentType":"CHECKOUT","author":null,"actionType":"CAMPAIGN","actionId":338,"comment":"test","deadlineAt":1584970652000,"campaignType":"DONATION","recurring":null,"amount":3.0000,"currency":"EUR","fulfilled":true},{"id":5668,"createdAt":1584361174000,"updatedAt":null,"contentType":"CHECKOUT","author":null,"actionType":"CAMPAIGN","actionId":333,"comment":"Mnemotechnik","deadlineAt":1584965974000,"campaignType":"FEE","recurring":"WEEKLY","amount":1.0000,"currency":"EUR","fulfilled":false},{"id":5636,"createdAt":1584355611000,"updatedAt":null,"contentType":"CHECKOUT","author":null,"actionType":"CAMPAIGN","actionId":327,"comment":"string","deadlineAt":1584355611000,"campaignType":"DONATION","recurring":"WEEKLY","amount":10.5500,"currency":"EUR","fulfilled":false},{"id":5367,"createdAt":1584290738000,"updatedAt":1584290785000,"contentType":"MATCH","author":{"id":32,"teamName":"Team Content","teamShirtNumber":null,"role":"TEAM_LEAD","firstName":"Team Lead Jeremiah","lastName":"Dominguez Gorrin","profilePictureReference":"aca511ec-c552-4bce-90ce-d993684c5854"}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns above JSON and configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: `createdAt`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$..createdAt`
   - Match No: `-1`

   [image]
2. As the result you will have the following JMeter Variables:

   ```
   createdAt_1=1584434217000
   createdAt_2=1584375135000
   createdAt_3=1584373151000
   createdAt_4=1584372961000
   createdAt_5=1584365852000
   createdAt_6=1584361174000
   createdAt_7=1584355611000
   createdAt_8=1584290738000
   createdAt_matchNr=8
   ```
3. Given you're interested in the last value you need to get `createdAt_8` variable value, it can be done using [__V() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) like:

   ```
   ${__V(createdAt_${createdAt_matchNr})}
   ```

   [image]

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dmitri T, your method worked as I wanted.